# Performance Point 2010 Filter Problem

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, business-intelligence, performancepoint

i have sharepoint 2010 Portal and created Performance point Dashboard in this portal 
the dashboard contains page that have Report and Filters
these filters is multi tree filter type
the problem that i am unable to expand filter tree in arabic website which is RTL
but in English site it works good.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

PerformancePoint 2010 doesn't fully support RTL languages. Here's a knowledge-base article on the topic:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982237